# Solve for $r$ and $\theta$ of $z^6$

Tags: complex-numbers, polar-coordinates

$z=(-1+\sqrt(3)i)$
Find r and theta for polar form when $z^6$.

I am unsure how to solve for this. I have got $r=2$ and $\theta=\frac {\pi}3$ for regular $z$, but I am unsure how to deal with the exponent.

Comment: If $z = re^{i\theta}$, then $z^k = r^k e^{ik\theta}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation of angle is wrong.

$$z=2e^{i2\pi/3}$$
Then
$$z^6=2^6e^{6(i2\pi/3)}=64e^{i4\pi}=64$$

Comment: Maybe OP intended $\tau/3$.

Comment: sorry @BrianTung $\tau$? did I miss something?

Comment: Why would the angle be $2\pi/3$? For $z$, I got $sin \theta=\frac{\sqrt 3}2$ so $\theta=\pi/3$.

Comment: @msm: $\tau = 2\pi$, an alternative constant to $\pi$, inspired by the notion that the ratio of circumference to radius is a bit more fundamental than the ratio of circumference to diameter.  (The unit circle is a circle of unit *radius*, not *diameter*.  And so on.)

Comment: $\theta=\arctan(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{-1})$ @user1766555

Comment: @user1766555: You can't just check the sine; you have to check the cosine, too.  And $\cos \pi/3 = 1/2$, which is positive, so it doesn't work.  By contrast, $\cos 2\pi/3 = -1/2$, which works, and $\sin 2\pi/3 = \sqrt{3}/2$, which also works.

Comment: @user1766555 You should use the correct definition of angle $$\theta=\arctan(\frac{Im(z)}{Re(z)})$$ to make sure the sign of both real and imaginary parts are taken into account.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you are claiming that $z=2e^{i\pi/3}$, then
$$
z^6=(2e^{i\pi/3})^6=...
$$

Comment: How can I get $r$ and $\theta$ from using that formula?

Comment: @user1766555 $z^6 = \rho e^{i\theta}$.

Comment: So, $(2e^{i\pi/3})^6 = (2^6e^{6i\pi/3}) = (64e^{i2\pi})$. Which gives $r=64, \theta=2\pi$, is that right?